# Crashing on strcpy, not sure why?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
   if (strlen(shortest) > strlen(longest)) {
            char *temp;
            strcpy(longest, temp);
            strcpy(shortest, longest);
            strcpy(temp, shortest);
     } 
 }
```

`strcpy(longest, temp)` --> is causing my program to crash. Here is a detailed crash report (I've included the proper header file, so it's not that. Also compiler warned me of using uninitialied temp variable...):

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __strcpy_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S:85
>   85      ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        char *temp;
        strcpy(longest, temp);
```

`strcpy` is `strcpy(dst, src)` not `strcpy(src, dst)`. The source is the parameter on the right, not the parameter on the left.

Moreover `char *temp` is not initialized when you pass its value to `strcpy`. You need to allocate memory for `temp` to hold the string you copy, for example using `malloc`

Comment: @girlrockingguna you have to also address the second point of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors.

> 1) You need to first "allocate" memory for char *temp;
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> char *temp;
> temp = malloc(4); // Allocate 4 character space. 
>                   // Ensure to include #include <stdlib.h>2)
> ```
>
> 2) strcpy signature is strcpy( dest, src ). In your code it is strcpy( src, dest ) whih is wrong.
>
> Correct Example:
>   `strccpy(temp, longest);`